# Trying to make a balanced delimiter checker in java using stacks while getting input from the user

Tags: java, stack

As talked about above I am trying to create a balanced delimiter checker in java. I have seen several examples of how to make one all of which were well done, but I have not found any that deal with having to get input from the user with the stack. I have looked into it, but I have not been able to find much with it. Below is what I have so far. I have been working on it but I have done more to confuse myself than anything else. Am I looking at this the right way? Or is there a better route to go about this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class BalancedParenthensies 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = input.nextLine();

        Stack<Character> S = new Stack<Character>();
        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("Enter: ");
            Character z= input.nextLine();//this line is not working
            S.push(z); 
        }
        for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = line.charAt(i);
            // do something with c
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course the line is not working. `nextLine()` returns a `String`, and that is not assignment compatible with `Character`. If you want the first `char`, call `charAt(0)`, after verifying that `length() == 1`. However, you are more likely wanting to iterate all the characters of the string.

Comment: Yes, getting user input is one problem, and creating a balanced delimiter check is another problem. I think you are expecting too much if you are Googling for "balanced delimiter check with user input". Break down your problem and make sure you can understand and can implement each component before rushing into things.

Comment: BTW: `input.hasNext()` will likely never be false.

Comment: It will if you end the stream (with Ctrl+D on Linux). Each terminal has a way to close `stdin`.